How to automatically format cmake files to comply with ROS2 ament_lint_cmake?
The ROS2 ament suite has a linter (ament_lint_cmake) that checks for proper formatting of cmake files such as CMakeLists.txt.
Is there a formatter that can reformat a cmake file to comply with the linter, preferably using vscode?
I tried the cmake-format extension to vscode but the ament cmake linter (which uses cmake-lint) is not happy with some of the formatting choices of cmake-format, in particular the indentation on line break. It also reformats the license header files.
